# Mobile responsiveness in Next _app.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, responsiveness

so in our current CRA app we handle responsiveness with a context provider that relies on the client width.

I am migrating into Next (yay) and just realized that the following will not work inside of `_app.js`

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { MobileContext } from "../contexts/MobileContext";
// ../contexts/MobileContext simply contains a react import and the below line:
// export const MobileContext = React.createContext(null);
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const isMobile = () => {
  const { clientWidth } = document.body;
  return clientWidth <= 768;
};


function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [mobile, setMobile] = useState(isMobile());
  useEffect(() => {
    const onResize = () => {
      setMobile(isMobile());
    };
    window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", onResize);
    };
  }, []);


  return (
  <MobileContext.Provider value={mobile}>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </MobileContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Because `document` isn't accessible when doing SSR..... shoot.

Would love to know the standard or typical solutions for responsiveness using next. Our dashboard has completely different components (well, kinda) when a user is on mobile, so it would be kind of a pain to handle all of the responsiveness with CSS media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you actually only have one option:

Use a static default value for your `mobile` state. This ensures that you don't rely on a browser value during SSR as the server doesn't know anything about the client.

Example:

```js
// ...
const [mobile, setMobile] = useState(true);
// ...
```

It depends on your application which default state makes most sense. If you follow a mobile first approach and ship only a small set of features to your mobile clients it might make sense use mobile as the default value.